# php, mysql how can I produce a dynamic html with fields in the first column and data in the next colums?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I found this great example which takes an sql statement and dynamically adds the field names into a header row and the data into the following rows?

Heres the example http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4249.html

Comment: I believe that applying the same approach given in your example, you can achieve this without a problem. I would first attempt, and then if you get stuck come back and post your code.

Comment: What DOESN'T the example do that you want to be able to do?

Comment: there's a reason for that. I'd suggest editing the extra code into the question. Click the 'edit' link below the tags to update/revise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTML tables **must** be written out by **row**, you'll have to read all the data before you're able to write out your table.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $rows[] = $row;

// We'll use the first row to get the field names:
foreach($rows[0] as $field => $throwaway) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
    // And for each field iterate through ALL rows:
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row[$field]) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: With the array-population code included in my example: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $rows[] = $row;`

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realise $rows = array() was just a declaration. I'm now getting results, but the first row and second row are the same, I'm not getting any field names.

Comment: Whoops — should be outputting `$field` not `$throwaway`. Edited.